# Generating SWIG code based on Python version

Tags: python, swig

I have some typemaps that I need to use PyInt if I'm compiling for Python 2 and PyLong if I'm compiling for Python 3. I tried to do this:

```
#if PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x03000000
%typemap(in) ssize_t {
    $1 = PyLong_AsSsize_t($input);
}
#else
%typemap(in) ssize_t {
    $1 = PyInt_AsSsize_t($input);
}
#endif
```

(In this example, `ssize_t` is a typedef-ed integral type.)

However, this takes the second branch, and then complains that PyInt is not defined (since PyInt does not exist in Python 2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro `PY_VERSION_HEX` is only defined when compiling the code (and including the python header), but not when SWIG parses the code. You can use the following instead:

```
%typemap(in) ssize_t {
%#if PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x03000000
    $1 = PyLong_AsSsize_t($input);
%#else
    $1 = PyInt_AsSsize_t($input);
%#endif
}
```

EDIT: Sorry, needed to fix the answer. The `%#...` syntax tells the SWIG preprocessor to copy the code verbatim.